# No sound on speakers, headphones ok

Tags: ubuntu, audio, laptop

My Laptop (Dell Vostro 3300) internal speaker (yes, it's mono) is mute already for some time, and I was just patient with this problem, because the sound quality is ridiculous anyway and I always used either headphones or external speakers. But I wanted to fix this nevertheless, for those few times I need that pity internal speaker.

There was no problem initially, but it appeared something like couple of months ago. It might be related to OS upgrades (Ubuntu 12.04 LTE right now), but, on the other hand, if I boot Live Mint 12, then there's no sound on speakers there neither. I thought that the problem might be hardware related (ie, the speaker is just plain dead), but I'm not sure how I could check that. Another explanation could be that the system thinks that the earphones jack is plugged in and the system just doesn't switch to the speaker output.

I surely hope this is some strange driver problem though and, thus, fixable. Would be happy for any ideas how to detect that.

Edit: I have increasing suspicion that the failed sense pin in headphone jack is to blame, so this is not Unix/Linux topic at all. Alas, there are no tests on this model to detect that.

Answer (score 3):

Launch `alsamixer` in terminal, press F4, and see if you have a `Capture` column, check if the volume is above zero, also,

**It might be muted**

[image]

Otherwise it would be like this:

[image]

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 I see no Capture column.

Answer (score 1):

Run various volume settings programs such as [`alsamixergui`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/alsamixergui) and check that all relevant volume controls are set to a sufficient volume. Sometimes multiple controls apply to one output, so if any of these are mute you don't get any sound.

It's possible that there's a mechanical failure: most laptops have a mechanical switch that turns off the internal speaker if a headphone jack is plugged in, and I've known these switches to break after a while. Try wiggling a jack in the hole, it might trip the switch.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you must do here is  let us know what the command lspci gives you as an output . Without that , understanding what is happening here becomes a tough problem. I can give you the different steps to check out whether something is wrong here, but it will take a lot of time and by that time you may lose your patience . Hence, i will give you two links which people have frequently used to solve their internal speaker problem after installing Ubuntu 12.04 PP (including me) . Here they are :

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1042840

http://yourenotabowler.blogspot.in/2009/01/sound-warz.html

Look at the second link for this one has helped me a lot for fixing the same issue in my HP laptop.